# how to display subview of superview?

Tags: iphone

How to implement code automatically displaying the subview of the superview after 3sec without clicking any button in iPhone?

Comment: This makes no sense, and your question text contradicts your title. Please edit the question and / or title with more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3
                                                      target: self
                                                    selector:@selector(showSuperView)
                                                    userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
```

If you want to show superview of childview then

```
-(void)showSuperView
{
[childView superview].hidden = NO;
}
```

and if you want to show childView of superview then

```
-(void)showchildView
    {
    for([UiView* v in superview.subviews])
{
//implement the condition to identify concerned childView
v.hidden = NO;
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *current=[[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
NSTimer *timer=[[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:current interval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(gotoNextView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO]autoreleas];

- (IBAction) gotoNextView 
{
    yourNextView *obj=[[[yourNextView alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourNextView" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
}
```

Hope this helpful!:)